# My Random Walk Java Program isn't working correctly. Any ways to Fix?

Tags: java

So, I have been writing this program called the Random Walk Bridge Program. So we have to run 50 trials and get the average amount of steps taken and the maximum amounts of steps taken. I have done this part but the part I am stuck on is this, in pic below.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uJbW.png

So Far this is my code for it, my code just has the dot in the middle and doesn't move and when I ask for the length, ex: 3. The bridge has 6 dashes instead of 3. My result-

|---*---|

|---*---|

|---*---|

|---*---|

|---*---|

|---*---|

Main Class-

```
public class BridgeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
        BridgeSecond object = new BridgeSecond();
        System.out.println("Length:");
        int length = reader.readInt();
        object.Output(length);
        object.bridge(length);
    }

}
```

Second Class

```
    public void bridge(int sizeOfbridge) {
                
        Random rand = new Random();
                
        int avg=0; int max=0; int min=0;
        int position = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<50;i++) {
            
            position=0; int count=0;
            
            while (position!=4 && position!=-4) {
                int number= rand.nextInt((1) + 1) + 0;
                if (number==1) {
                    position++;
                }
                if (number==0) {
                    position--;
                }
                count++;
            }
            avg=avg+count;
            
            if (count>max) {
                max=count;  
            }

            System.out.print("|");
            for (count=1;count<=sizeOfbridge;count++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
     
            for (count=1;count<=sizeOfbridge;count++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your picture of ASCII content as text, not as link to a picture of text.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: The part of your code that is printing dashes and asterisk and such is going to print 50 identical lines that have nothing to do with the random walks you took.  This is so because that code depends only on the variable `sizeOfbridge`, which never changes during the 50 iterations of the loop. So where is the code that generated what you've shown us in the image?

Comment: @Steve, the code is in the second class. It all the way on the bottom

Comment: No matter what you do, after this while loop there are only two possible values for position: 4 and -4. You could simplify this to whole loop to a simple `position = 4 * (rand.nextInt(1) == 0 ? -1 : 1)`.

Sure, you increment `count` on each loop iteration. but you don't *do* anything with that value later.

`for (count=1;count<=sizeOfbridge;count++)` resets count to `1`. Thus, the loop *always* runs from 1 to `sizeOfBridge`. Similarly your other loop. Similarly, you can remove `avg`, `count`, `min`, `max` and `position`. You calculate all these values without actually *using* them.